# TP-Link TL-WN821N on Mac OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard (atheros ar7010 + ar9287)

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers

I have a spare TP-Link TL-WN821N wireless USB adapter and I'd love to use it on my Snow Leopard.

Any chances to do it with some hacking since official drivers are Windows-only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use software on your Mac OSX called 'Desktop Parallels' with windows XP or Windows 7 so you can start that program, install your USB WLAN as you would on those operating systems and use the net.

Not great but it works!

Comment: So your answer about how to use TL-WN821N in OS X is to use it in Windows instead?!